# Inline std::mutex in header file

Tags: c++, c++17, inline-variable

I am using a global `std::mutex` in different cpp files.

Is it okay to declare it in a header file as `inline`?

```
inline std::mutex mtx;
```

Is `mtx` constructed this way?

Should it be initialized explicitly? As in:

```
inline std::mutex mtx = {};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation on `inline` keyword applied to a variable (C++17)
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)
it is stated that

```
2) It has the same address in every translation unit.
```

and

```
If an inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage is defined differently in different translation units, the behavior is undefined.
```

I understand from these sentences that the mutex will actually be unique and correctly initialised (if the only header suggested is used)

Comment: Doesn't `Because the meaning of the keyword inline for functions came to mean "multiple definitions are permitted" rather than "inlining is preferred", that meaning was extended to variables.` conflict with what you say?

Comment: @ JVApen I don't think so, because, in order to prevent undefined behaviour, those multiple definitions have to be exactly the same (one-definition-rule).

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 and above it is okay and proper to declare `mtx` as `inline`.  This allows you to have the same variable defined in all the translation units it is in.

> Should it be initialized explicitly? As in:
>
> ```
> inline std::mutex mtx = {};
> ```

That is not needed.  `std::mutex` is default constructable so `inline std::mutex mtx;` is all you need.

---

Before we had inline variables what you would have to do is have a header file with

```
extern std::mutex mtx;
```

in it and then in a single cpp file have

```
std::mutex mtx;
```

in it to actually provide a single definition.

Comment: There was also the static function variable approach: `inline std::mutex &getMtx() { static std::mutex mtx; return mtx; }`.